Синонимизировать метки [zoom] и [масштабирование]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

zoom (38 вопросов)
масштабирование (71 вопрос)

у обеих нет описания
Основная - масштабирование, т. к. с ней больше вопросов и она на русском.

Осторожно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1270743

@andreymal, .

Не стоит забывать и про рекомендации

@andreymal а подобного рода вопрос разве онтопик? Я бы такой закрыл и вообще удалил.... Если бы было zoom-api, то я бы ещё понял...а тут...

@АлексейШиманский я бы много чего закрыл и удалил даже из того, что здесь называют онтопиком ¯\(ツ)/¯

@andreymal мне кажется самое простое - просто плыть и отпустить)) Имхо никогда ruSO не будет тем, что мы хотим, т.к. многие видят его по-разному. Сообщество - это и сильная сторона ресурса и самая его большая проблема. Все разные и видят правильность по-своему. Самое оптимальное, по сути, запустить свой подобный ресурс, но со своими правилами, причём тоталитарными, где решающий человек -  сверху один, который знает как он видит систему и что хочет, чтобы было))) А тут - тут даже создателям нафиг не упало ничего))

Так можно ж еще проще - сделать своё зеркало SO (CC BY SA позволяет) и отфильтровать из него то что вам не нравится :-) А по серьезному - поставить минус и забыть.

Похоже, что в этот раз синонимизировать метки всё же не стоит. Как указали в комментариях, их использование на имеющихся вопросах не так однозначно.
Для предложения удачной синонимизации меток в дальнейшем стоит руководствоваться имеющимися рекомендациями.
